# Returning an image from RSS in gatsby-plugin-feed

Tags: graphql, rss, gatsby, gatsby-image

I'm trying to return an author image from the frontmatter of a blog post. The front matter is structured as such;

```
---
title: XXX
date: "XXX"
description: "XXX"
featuredImage: './featured-image.jpg'
avatar: './author.jpg'
author: 'XXX'
---
```

In gatsby-config I have gatsby-plugin-feed set up like this -

```
{
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-feed`,
      options: {
        query: `
          {
            site {
              siteMetadata {
                title
                author
                siteUrl
                site_url: siteUrl
              }
            }
          }
        `,
        feeds: [
          {
            serialize: ({ query: { site, allMarkdownRemark } }) => {
              return allMarkdownRemark.edges.map(edge => {
                return Object.assign({}, edge.node.frontmatter, {
                  description: edge.node.frontmatter.description,
                  date: edge.node.frontmatter.date,
                  url: site.siteMetadata.siteUrl + edge.node.fields.slug,
                  avatar: edge.node.frontmatter.avatar,
                  custom_elements: [{ "content:encoded": edge.node.html }],
                })
              })
            },
            query: `
              {
                allMarkdownRemark(
                  sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date] },
                ) {
                  edges {
                    node {
                      excerpt
                      html
                      fields { slug }
                      frontmatter {
                        title
                        date
                        author
                        description
                        avatar
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            `,
            output: "/rss.xml",
            title: "Your Site's RSS Feed",
          },
        ],
      },
    },
```

This causes an error  `Error: Field "avatar" of type "File" must have a selection of subfields. Did you mean "avatar { ... }"?`
How do I change this so that an image URL is returned in the RSS feed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The initial query needs to call for the `image_url` and `rssMetadata`, also there is missing code that is part of the RSS-plugin query which is needed to work properly

`guid: rssMetadata.site_url + edge.node.fields.slug`

[Gatsby RSS Feed Docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-an-rss-feed/) Are also pretty helpful

```
query: `
        {
          site {
            siteMetadata {
              rssMetadata {
                site_url
                title
                author
                image_url
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `,
        feeds: [
          {
            serialize: ({ query: { site, allMarkdownRemark } }) => {
              return allMarkdownRemark.edges.map(edge => {
                return Object.assign({}, edge.node.frontmatter, {
                  description: edge.node.frontmatter.description,
                  date: edge.node.frontmatter.date,
                  url: rssMetadata.site_url + edge.node.fields.slug,
                  guid: rssMetadata.site_url + edge.node.fields.slug,
                  avatar: edge.node.frontmatter.avatar,
                  custom_elements: [{ "content:encoded": edge.node.html }],
                })
              })
            },
```

Lastly it is possible that `avatar` needs to be called as a `custom_element`

```
custom_elements: [
                    { "avatar": edge.node.frontmatter.avatar},
                    { "content:encoded": edge.node.html }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm running into the error -  Error: Cannot query field "rssMetadata" on type "SiteSiteMetadata".

Comment: make sure the .md file is in order title
                        date
                        author
                        description
                        avatar